# Getting error message: "The package appears to be corrupt."

Tags: java, android

I can get the message like this; "The package appears to be corrupt", 
when I install the debug apk to my phone.
In the S6, S7, S5, all are the same.
Who can help me to solve this problem?, thanks.

Comment: Hi, Lino.
It was a debug apk that I did build in the android studio.
What do you mean 'download'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways can be possible to solve this problem.

- Upgrade also plugin version when you have already upgrade Android studio to 3.0.
- Go to build / build apks.