# App Not Installed - This Package appears to be corrupt

Tags: android, package, installation, apk, corrupt

**Goal: Send APK to someone else to install on their phone**

I have an Android app that I made that has been working on my phone. I tried to send it to someone else but they are getting the error

> "App not installed. This package appears to be corrupt."

I am using a Galaxy S6 and they are using a Galaxy S8 (we are both using Android Version 7.)

How this relates to others: 
*Since originally making the app, I have worked on a different app and upgrading the gradle. I have also exported the APK for this new/different app as well (successfully). I'm not sure if either of these actions would cause a problem?*

---

Not sure what My Android Studio/Gradle was on, but it currently says Android Studio 2.3.2 and Gradle Version 3.3

---

What I have tried:

1. Exporting the signed APK from Android Studio (and emailed it)
2. Sent copy of APK from my Android Device (Galaxy S6) to my computer (and emailed it)
3. Building and rebuilding
4. Looked up stackoverflow articles on this such as: [Getting error message: "The package appears to be corrupt."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47140622/getting-error-message-the-package-appears-to-be-corrupt), ["The package appears to be corrupt" while installing APK on Galaxy S7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47338920/the-package-appears-to-be-corrupt-while-installing-apk-on-galaxy-s7)

What else could I be missing?

Comment: when installing the apk on other devices, you are sure there is no previous version of the app installed on that device ?!!

Answer (score -1):

Muhammed Refaat's comment to the question worked to resolve this same issue with an APK on my phone.

In my case I was also using a Galaxy S8 running Android Version 7.

I had an App that was installed from the App Store and then an APK of a newer version not yet on the app store. Trying to install from the APK gave a corrupt package error just as you mentioned.

I uninstalled the existing version from my S8 and installed from the APK and it worked successfully without a hitch. Didn't even need to restart the phone.